# Unable to solve some types error of flow in react-native

Tags: react-native, flowtype

**I decided to integrate flow in my project and unable to solve some types errors.i searched a lot but couldn't find what will be the types for below values.**

eg.

1. Type for references
2. type for Props for consturctor
3. Type for this.localNotifications(variable)
4. How to define type for when we bind method.

**I am sharing my code below and with errors I am getting. Thanks in advance**

```
    /*** @flow*/

    import { Component } from 'react';
    import * as React from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity,
  AppState,
  Alert,
  TextInput
} from 'react-native';
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view';
import PhoneInput from 'react-native-phone-input';
import {
  StackActions,
  NavigationActions,
  NavigationScreenProps
} from 'react-navigation';
import { ProgressDialog } from 'react-native-simple-dialogs';
import { styles } from './Styles';
import { FloatingLabelInput, CTAButton } from 'Components';
import { strings } from '../../../utility/locales/i18n';
import AppUtil from 'Library/Utils/AppUtil';
import * as DateUtil from 'Library/Utils/DateUtil';
import { R } from 'Resources';
import { inject, observer } from 'mobx-react/native';
import { Query } from 'react-apollo';
import { USER_TYPE, USER_ONBOARDING_STEP } from 'Library/Constants';
import * as UserQueries from 'AppSyncQueries/UserQueries';
import LocalNotification from '../../../Components/LocalNotification/LocalNotification';
import PushNotificationController from '../../../Components/LocalNotification/PushNotificationController';
import moment from 'moment';
type Props = NavigationScreenProps & {};
type passwordRef = {|
  current: any | null
|};

type State = {
  userName: string,
  password: string,
  loading: boolean,
  valid: boolean,
  shouldLoadProfile: boolean
};

@inject('loginUserStore', 'userAccountStore', 'measurementUnitStore')
@observer
export class Login extends Component<Props, State> {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: strings('login.title'),
    header: null
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.passwordRef = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
      userName: '',
      password: '',
      loading: false,
      valid: false,
      shouldLoadProfile: false,
      startProgramDate: this.props.userAccountStore.programStartDate
    };
    this.updateInfo = this.updateInfo.bind(this);
    this.localNotification = new LocalNotification();
    this.scheduleLocalNotification = this.scheduleLocalNotification.bind(this);
  }

  onChangeText(key: string, value: string) {
    this.setState({ password: value });
  }

  updateInfo() {
    this.setState({
      valid: this.phone.isValidNumber()
    });
  }

  gotoDashboard() {
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(AppUtil.resetAction('Dashboard', {}));
  }


  completeNewPassword(user: any) {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('SetPassword', { user: user });
  }


  startPasswordReset() {
    const title = strings('login.password_reset_required_title');
    const message = strings('login.password_reset_required_message');
    Alert.alert(title, message, [
      {
        text: 'Ok',
        onPress: () => {
          this.props.navigation.navigate('ResetPassword', {
            userName: this.phone.getValue()
          });
        }
      }
    ]);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <KeyboardAwareScrollView
        style={{ backgroundColor: R.Colors.COLOR_APP_BACKGROUND }}
        scrollEnabled
        extraScrollHeight={50}
        enableResetScrollCoords
        resetScrollToCoords={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
      >
        <View style={styles.container}>
          {AppUtil.renderProgressBar(
            this.state.loading,
            strings('common_message.please_wait')
          )}

          <Image source={R.Images.logo} style={styles.appLogo} />

          <View style={styles.loginContainer}>
            <TextInput
              style={{ height: 35, color: '#929CA5', fontSize: 14 }}
              editable={false}
              selectTextOnFocus={false}
              value='Phone Number'
            />

            <View style={styles.userName}>
              <PhoneInput
                onPressFlag={this.onPressFlag}
                ref={ref => {
                  this.phone = ref;
                }}
              />
            </View>

            <View style={{ marginTop: 15, marginLeft: 1 }}>
              <FloatingLabelInput
                style={styles.textField}
                secureTextEntry
                label='Password'
                returnKeyType='done'
                ref={this.passwordRef}
                value={this.state.password}
                onChangeText={text => this.setState({ password: text })}
              />
            </View>

            <View style={styles.forgotPasswordBtnContainer}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.gotoForgotPassword.bind(this)}>
                <Text style={styles.forgotPasswordBtn}>Forgot Password?</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>

            <CTAButton
              label='LOGIN'
              isEnabled={true}
              onClick={this.loginClick.bind(this)}
              style={{ marginTop: 30 }}
            />

          </View>
          <PushNotificationController />
        </View>
      </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

**If you check code of constructor you will find many variables and references are used.Still I would love to describe each error , That will helpful to understand**

> 1. Missing type annotation for props.(for constructor props)
> 2. Cannot assign React.createRef() to this.passwordRef because property passwordRef is missing in Login[1]
> 3. Cannot assign this.updateInfo.bind(...) to this.updateInfo because property updateInfo is not writable.
> 4. Cannot assign new LocalNotification() to this.localNotification because property localNotification is missing in Login[1]